# Can't use sudo with newly created Ubuntu user via ansible

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vagrant, ansible, ubuntu-16.04

I'm running a Xenial 16.04 VM using vagrant. The VM comes out of the box with a `vagrant` user with the vagrant password without a password for `root`( though Ubuntu still requires a password if you ssh into root@ubuntu-vm) 
In order to simulate a production VPS, I created a `deployer` user using this playbook:

```
- user:
    name: deployer
    groups: admin
    password: "{{ deployer_password }}"
    shell: /bin/bash

- name: "read authorized keys from root user"
  become_user: vagrant
  command: "cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
  register: "root_authorized_keys"

- debug: msg="{{root_authorized_keys}}"

- name: "create .ssh dir for deployer"
  file: path="/home/deployer/.ssh" state=directory


- name: "copy authorized keys to deployer user"
  shell: "echo '{{root_authorized_keys.stdout}}' > /home/deployer/.ssh/authorized_keys"


- name: "chown the authorized_keys file"
  file: path="/home/deployer/.ssh" recurse=yes mode=0700 owner="deployer"
```

When I ssh into `deployer@ubuntu-vm` I'm asked to type the password then I logged in the VM as one should expect. Also `sudo` and `sudo su` work as expected after I type in the password for the `deployer` user.

The problem arises when I try to `sudo` via an Ansible playbook or via an Ansible ad-hoc command.

Note the responses I get for the following 4 Ansible commands:

```
$ ansible all -m ping -u vagrant
ubuntu-vm | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false, 
    "ping": "pong"
}

$ ansible all -m ping -u deployer
ubuntu-vm | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false, 
    "ping": "pong"
}

$ ansible all -m ping -u vagrant --sudo
ubuntu-vm | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false, 
    "ping": "pong"
}

$ ansible all -m ping -u deployer --sudo
ubuntu-vm | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "failed": true, 
    "module_stderr": "sudo: a password is required\n", 
    "module_stdout": "", 
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE"
}
```

**What options do I have to use `sudo` for `deployer` successfully?**

*Also take into account that the `remote_user` for the `ubuntu-vm` host will be both `vagrant` and the `deployer` users. If possible, I would like a way to use both in a playbook( example: I use the `vagrant` user to create the `deployer` user and then I use the `deployer` user for other plays)*

Answer (score 2):

Try `--ask-sudo-pass`

It will prompt for password.

```
ansible all -m ping -u deployer --sudo --ask-sudo-pass
```

In Ansible 1.9+, it is recommended to use `--become` and `--ask-become-pass` since `--sudo` and `--ask-sudo-pass` are deprecated. [Become (Privilege Escalation)](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html)

Comment: Can this be used with `ansible-playbook` as well? If so how can I pass the passwords for multiple users? ( see the italic text I wrote after my question above)

Comment: The `--ask-become-pass` works if I need to pass the password for only one user but I can't figure out how to pass the passwords for multiple users.

Comment: I do not think it is possible to pass passwords for multiple users unless you use Ansible Vault. See: http://serverfault.com/questions/560106/how-can-i-implement-ansible-with-per-host-passwords-securely

Comment: I do use Ansible Vault. The `deployer_password` variable you see in the user creation task above come from an `secrets.yml` file encrypted with `ansible-vault`.

Comment: It was straight forward to use the `deployer_password` during the user creation. I just had to set the `password` attribute. I tried setting a `password/ansible_become_pass` attribute for the play where `remote_user` is set to `deployer` and apparently both is an invalid attributes.